# Drag and Drop Images across different domains like Google Image Search

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How does Google exactly do that? That is, the ability to drag an image from another domain like facebook.com and using it to search?

Using jQuery and the `drop` event we can't really do so as we're having cross-domain limitation exceptions if we got the url and then made an XMLHttpRequest. Is there a way around this problem?

Comment: what is the limitation you facing?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load <url>. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: will jsonp help you ?  http://docs.jquery.com/Release:jQuery_1.2/Ajax

Comment: My guess is google does it by storing the image on their own servers and implement CORS.

Comment: @zod Unfortunately no, I'm looking into being able to drag images from ANY domain, exactly how Google does it, jsonp doesn't seem to be capable of that nor does it work..

Comment: @KevinB Interesting.. Will look into that and update.

Comment: google need actual url to that image. so i believe it will get that image using url and  search for similar. When i try to drag some images like SO icon ,  google give me error "The URL doesn't refer to an image, or the image is not publicly accessible."

Comment: @zod I've tried private images on facebook and they worked.. :/

Comment: am just saying the url should be proper. no other magic to extract image. if you found something post it .thanks

Comment: I can get the url from the dragged object but I can't make a request. There's definitely no magic in there and Google is already doing it so it's definitely doable. Will post results if found.